# Bloomberglp.Blpapi Adding Reference

Tags: c#, bloomberg

I am new to Bloomberg API, trying to develop my first C# application.

I have installed the blp API. I have with Visual Studio 2008 added a reference to blpapicomLib COM object.

I have defined and alias like this:

```
using SessionOptions = blpapicomLib.SessionOptions;
```

When I try to create a new SessionOptions like this:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
```

I receive the error:

> Error 1   Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'blpapicomLib.SessionOptions'  C:\AMSFeederTest\VarPricesLib\VarPricesLib\VarPrices.cs 23  45  VarPricesLib

What library reference should I add to my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Session = Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Session;
using SessionOptions = Bloomberglp.Blpapi.SessionOptions;

SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
sessionOptions.ServerHost = serverHost; //localhost
sessionOptions.ServerPort = serverPort; //8194

Session session = new Session(sessionOptions);

...
...
```